# forward Authorization token to routed microservices with zuul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices, netflix-zuul

I've been using Zuul to make an API Gateway which holds most of the SecurityConfig, and made a Jwt based Authenticaiton, however I don't know why, whenever I request one of the routes to my microservice, the Request Header, doesn't contain the Authorization even if I did `zuul.myMicroservice.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply make a "pre" ZuulFilter and add a Header which contains the Authorization token

Though, you won't see that header show up in Postman, it is still there and you can intercept it in your microservice by makign a filter that inherits OncePerRequest and call this on doFilter Internal:

```java
String authHeaderParam  = request.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).nextElement();
```